# Using Buzz.js audio starts from last where i stopped instead of start from beginning. (ipad1)

Tags: html, audio, mobile-safari, html5-audio, buzz.js

I am using buzz.js library for html. I have a HTML list element where every list element has a specific audio. i want to play audio on click event of list and also on next and previous buttons. so i wrote below code for that, it's working on desktop browsers. when i am testing it on mobile safari (ipad1). when i am playing audio second time it is started from where it is stopped on last time. i want to start audio from beginning.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var mainIntro = new buzz.sound( "audio/intro", {formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "aac" ], preload: true, autoplay: true, loop: false});
var slide1 = new buzz.sound( "audio/slide1", {formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "aac" ], preload: true, autoplay: true, loop: false});
function introAudio() {
    buzz.all().stop();          
    mainIntro.play().bind('ended', function(e){
        document.getElementById("blinkRed").style.visibility="visible";
    }); 
}
function slide1Audio() {
    buzz.all().stop();  
    slide1.play().bind('ended', function(e){
        document.getElementById("blinkRed").style.visibility="visible";
    });     
}
$('#navHolder ul li a').click(function() {

    if (myIndex == -1){ 
        $('#slideHolder').attr('src',"introMain.html");         
        myIndex = -1;
        introAudio();

    }       
    else if (myIndex == 0){
        $('#slideHolder').attr('src',"intro.html");
        myIndex = 0;
        slide1Audio();
    }
else if (myIndex == 1){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it comes up on Google searches so I thought I would answer.

I had a similar problem like this before and to fix it you have to add a line of code. It only seems to happen in WebKit based browsers.

Add:

```
    mySound.load();
```

This reloads the audio file and it starts from the beginning.